# Postgres: Is there a query to return the tables owned by a given user?

Tags: postgresql

I need a query (not a command like \dn or \dt or whatnot as I am not running this from the command line) that will let me specify a username, and get all of the tables associated with that user (and ideally how much disk space it is using and other details).

Does such a command exist? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up such information in the [catalog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/catalogs.html). The catalog is a collection of tables containing meta data about a running Postgres instance. Therefore it is easy to query with SQL. To find all tables owned by a particular user you can query [`pg_tables`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/view-pg-tables.html). For sizes you probably have to join [`pg_class`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/catalog-pg-class.html).

Comment: Perfect. I also found this site: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html which helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This will provide the table name, and its owner as well as the userid

```
SELECT pgc.relname, pgc.relowner, pgs.usename 
FROM pg_class pgc JOIN pg_shadow pgs 
ON pgc.relowner = pgs.usesysid;
```