# Command to show all tables owned by a specific user

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I use the `\d` command in `psql`, I get a list of tables and sequences of all users.

Is there a command which will display only the tables which a specific user is the owner?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677729/postgres-is-there-a-query-to-return-the-tables-owned-by-a-given-user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a psql command:

```
select c.relname, relkind
from
    pg_class c
    inner join
    pg_roles r on r.oid = c.relowner
where
    r.rolname = 'that_owner'
    and
    c.relkind = 'r'
order by c.relname
```

If you want tables and sequences:

```
    and
    c.relkind in ('r', 'S')
```